# JavaScript: simplest way to get the date of the month 6 months prior on the first?

Tags: javascript

So if today was April 12, 2010 it should return October 1, 2009

Some possible solutions I've googled seem overly complex, any suggestions?

Comment: I have used Date function to find todays date.

Comment: please put your code ,it will be help us to know what is problem with yoi

Comment: Do you mean "October 1**2**, 2009"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two dates

```
var date = new Date(2010, 3, 12);
var date6MonthsAgo = new Date(date);
date6MonthsAgo.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 6);

// and to set it to the first date of the month
date6MonthsAgo.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: I am getting the output but the date is same as todays date .

Comment: Today date is 23/04/2016 when i execute this code im getting 23/10/2015. So the two dates are same, only the month changes is there anyway to change date when month is changed.

Comment: And another problem is ,if today is March 31 and if i am doing like this   Im getting feb 31 as output. So whats the error here ????                                                            dateoneMonthsAgo.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);

Answer (score 0):

moment.js is a great JavaScript library for displaying and manipulating Date/Time

http://momentjs.com/

In this case you would use: `var date = moment().subtract(6, 'months').toString();`

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/aadoy9qo/